# How can I sync two `.git` local repositories with unique branch commits?

Tags: git

Both `.git` repositories are on the same machine but different folders, and belong esentially to the same project. To keep it simple, let's say both copies have two branches:

- The `master` (or Alpha) branch. Last commits to this branch were made in `folderA`'s `.git` repository.
- The `stable` (or Beta) branch. Last commits to this branch were made in `folderB`'s `·git repository`

So, I want to make both branches hold the last changes in both `git` folders again. So, after cleaning both working directories, I guess I just could copy the whole directory project's files from `folderB` and make a single commit to the `stable` branch inside `folderA`. However, I'd like to conserve all the commits from `folderB` as well instead. (next time I should not forget to copy the master `.git` directory to the beta folder before making any hotfixes to the Beta version so I would not have this problem anymore; but what is done is done ^^')

If it was "local to remote", making a "pull request" would be the way to go I guess. But in my case, both copies of the repository are on the same machine.

Is there any git command to perform such a thing?

Comment: add remotes that point to local directories.

Comment: So, it would be like a `git remote add` using `file:///` instead of `http://` or `ftp://`? More or less?

Comment: That's right. so file:/// http://, ssh:// sft:// they are just `transports` for git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a local repository as a remote and use `git pull` and handle merge conflicts, etc. as usual

For example

```bash
$ cd /path/to/folderB/
$ git remote add localA /path/to/folderA
$ git checkout master
$ git pull localA master
```

Comment: Fine, I will feel better trying it this way now. Thank you